# How to prevent association from changing on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
end
```

And the route:

```
resources :posts, only: %i[create update]
```

And my controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:update]

  PERMITED_POST_PARAMS = [
    :site_id,
    :title,
    :url,
    :body,
  ].freeze

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(*PERMITED_POST_PARAMS)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(id)
  end

  def id
    params[:id]
  end
end
```

The `site_id` can be changed on the update. Would it be possible to flag this property to only be assigned on creation and raise an error on update?

There is no need to use nested routes (`/sites/:site_id/posts` and `/sites/:site_id/posts/:id`) in this case because I can know the `id` of the post that I want to update (so the property `site_id` is only needed for creating a post), and I also prefer a code more self contained code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using different permitted params, for create and update:

```
def create_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:site_id, :title, :url, :body)
end

def update_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :url, :body)
end
```

---

One more thing, if you are using nested routes, instead of finding the post from all posts (`Post.find(params][:id])`), you should find it from the posts that belong to the site_id: `@site = Site.find(params[:site_id]); @site.posts.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I guess that would be a possibility. I see you have a lot of knowledge on rails. Would you recommend me solving the issue differently than what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: My answer is what I would recommend, two sets of permitted parameters (I do it often), you are right that you don't need the site_id in the URL for updating, but to keep it consistent is better to use nested routes for the controller and not just for the create.

Comment: I see. Ok, I will listen to your advice since you're definitely more experienced in the matter. Thank you Leonel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionController::Parameters#except`:

```
  # ...
  def update
    if @post.update(post_params.except(:site_id))
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Or you can extract the base parameters into a your constant and merge them with per action parameters:

```
# corrected the spelling.
PERMITTED_POST_PARAMS = %i{ title url body }.freeze

def create_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:site_id, *PERMITTED_POST_PARAMS)
end

def update_params
   params.require(:post).permit(*PERMITTED_POST_PARAMS)
end
```